# Tensorboard TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'

Tags: python, tensorflow, typeerror, tensorboard

I am using tensorflow version 1.3.0 and tensorboard version 1.10.0 I just updated my tensorboard version and after the update when I am trying to start tensorboard i got the following error message;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sztaki_user\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 193,
in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\sztaki_user\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 85, i
n _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Sztaki_user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\_
_main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sztaki_user\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorb
oard\main.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "c:\users\sztaki_user\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorb
oard\default.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import audio_plugin
  File "c:\users\sztaki_user\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorb
oard\plugins\audio\audio_plugin.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import metadata
  File "c:\users\sztaki_user\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorb
oard\plugins\audio\metadata.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import plugin_data_pb2
  File "c:\users\sztaki_user\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorb
oard\plugins\audio\plugin_data_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
    serialized_pb=_b('\n+tensorboard/plugins/audio/plugin_data.proto\x12\x0btens
orboard\"}\n\x0f\x41udioPluginData\x12\x0f\n\x07version\x18\x01 \x01(\x05\x12\x3
7\n\x08\x65ncoding\x18\x02 \x01(\x0e\x32%.tensorboard.AudioPluginData.Encoding\"
 \n\x08\x45ncoding\x12\x0b\n\x07UNKNOWN\x10\x00\x12\x07\n\x03WAV\x10\x0b\x62\x06
proto3')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'
```

I tried to change the tensorboards log directory with the following command: tensorboard --logdir=*the log directory*

Do you have any ideas how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

FIX:

I just updated my TensorBoard to version 1.9.0 and now its working!

Comment: Please provide us more details like, what have you tried already?

Comment: I just updated my tensorboard to version 1.9.0 and now it is working!

Comment: Well done peter! You can add the answer to your question and mark it as the answer in a couple of days. So your question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tensorflow is not installed properly (missing protobuf version issue)

follow the below steps,

```
sudo pip install tensorflow
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

then finally

```
sudo pip install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try execute this command

```
pip install -U protobuf
```

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: May be inconsistent versions of protobuf in the system